# How to make use of ground truth data in image anomaly detection?

Tags: neural-networks, dataset, image-processing, computer-vision, anomaly-detection

If I have an image dataset that consists of "normal", anomalous and ground truth image data, how do I make use of the ground truth data?

To my understanding if I train an unsupervised anomaly detection approach on "normal" images, it can then later predict whether an input image is "normal" or anomalous.

How can I make use of the ground truth data in this context? And what purpose has the ground truth data in anomaly detection in general?

Thanks in advance for any answers! I am relatively new to the field of anomaly detection.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a numeric ground truth such as how similar each image is to the normal subset.  Another option may be a ground truth mask which highlights which part of the image is anomalous.  If the ground truth is just another image it isn't clear what purpose it would serve.

Comment: Yes, the ground truth data tells me which parts of the anomalous images are anomalous. I just do not quite understand how I can use these to contribute to my anomaly detection approach.